# Rename/move .idea folder for IntelliJ project?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to rename the `.idea` folder that's automatically created by IntelliJ or move it to a different location?

Answer (score 5):

Renaming the .idea directory is not possible; IntelliJ IDEA always reads project files from the directory with that exact name, and it can't be changed.

Moving is sort of possible. The locations and content roots of modules in IntelliJ IDEA are completely independent from the location of the project itself. Because of that, you can create a project in a directory that doesn't contain any code, and set up modules with content roots pointing to the directories where the code is located.